# Minimum possible fold line

Tags: limits

> One corner of a strip of paper length $a$ is folded up so that it lies along the opposite edge. Find the least possible fold line. **Answer:$\frac{3 \sqrt3a}{4}$**
>   [image]

**Attempt**

Let $l$ be the fold length that is $l^2=x^2+y^2$

By some trigonometry we can work out

$y=\frac{a}{\sin\theta}  $

$x=\frac{a}{1+\cos\theta}  $

However I cant workout what they mean by fold line. Are they asking for minimum length of $l+x+y$ or just $l$?

Comment: The answer should be in terms of $a$

Comment: Oh yes thanks. Please see the edit.

Comment: Have you tried working out the minimum of $l$? It's very likely that is what they want. $l+x+y$ is unlikely to be a rational multiple of $\sqrt{3}$

Comment: Actually I tried but the answer is not coming right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\theta$ be the angle in the lower triangle defined in your diagram by $\tan\theta=\frac xy$

Then $a=y\sin2\theta$ and $y=l\sin\theta$ so that $$l=a\csc\theta\csc2\theta$$

Or, preferably, $$\frac 1l=\frac 2a\sin^2\theta\cos\theta$$

Differentiating, $$-\frac{1}{l^2}\frac{dl}{d\theta}=\frac 2a[2\sin\theta\cos^2\theta-\sin^3\theta]=0$$

From this we get $\tan\theta=\sqrt{2}$ and the result as expected follows immediately.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest making theta, the angle of the fold (the triangle bounded by $x,y,l$).

This means:

$y = l\cos\theta\\
x = l\sin\theta\\
a = y\sin 2\theta$

$a = l\cos\theta(2\sin\theta\cos\theta)\\
a = 2l\cos^2\theta\sin\theta\\
a = 2l(\sin\theta - \sin^3\theta)$

let $u = \sin\theta$

$a = 2l(u-u^2)$

To minimize $l$ you must maximize $u-u^3.$

Can you take it from here?